# Discord bot does not send message to channel

Tags: python, web-scraping, discord

I'm trying to make my bot send a message to a discord channel if certain conditions are met, but I can't seem to get the code working. The code checks every 5 seconds if a list contains the string '.12.' and should then forward the message.

```
import requests
import time
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

while True:
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('bot is active')

    url = 'website link'
    res = requests.get(url)
    html = res.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    html_element = soup.find_all( 'td', { "class" : "eksam-ajad-aeg" } )

    ret = []
    for t in html_element:
        ret.append(t.text)
    print(ret)

    if '.12.' in ret:
        @client.event
        async def send():
            channel = client.get_channel(758088198852182037)
            await channel.send('message')
        client.run('token')
        
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Putting your bot in a `while True` seems a bit unusual.  Generally, most people just call `client.run()` once at the end.  I'm not sure if this is the cause of your issue, but it is something that I notice is a bit unusual with your bot.

Edit: I think I know what you're trying to do now.  Asyncio might be a better way of going about that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Notably the `asyncio.sleep` portion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bot script that appears to be working.  Without having the url that you're attempting to search, I'm not able to help completely, but give this a try and see if it works for you:

```python
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    # Create a task and run check_html and feed it a parameter of 5 seconds
    client.loop.create_task(check_html(5))
    print("Bot is active")


async def check_html(time):
    while True:
        url = 'url here'
        res = requests.get(url)
        html = res.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        html_element = soup.find_all( 'td', { "class" : "eksam-ajad-aeg" } )

        ret = []

        for t in html_element:
            ret.append(t.text)
        print(ret)
        if '.12.' in ret:
            for guild in client.guilds:
                for channel in guild.channels:
                    if channel.id == 758088198852182037:
                        await channel.send('message')

        # Asyncronously sleep for 'time' seconds
        await asyncio.sleep(time)

client.run('token')
```